# AWS IOT Core rule trigger lambda function in different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot, aws-regions

I have my AWS IOT Core setup in AP-South-1 Region, all my devices are present there. But due to the region constraint of alexa skill service endpoint (i.e. only available in North Virginia, Ireland and Oregon), my lambda is in Ireland region (since it is nearest to AP-South-1). All this setup is working fine untill I needed to create a rule in AWS IOt Core. In action option of rule, I can only see lambda functions of same region i.e. Ap-South-1. Can I somehow create a rule in between two regions? Because shifting whole IOT Core seems complex and also I fear that it might increase latency in mqtt messages. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

AWS recommends that you invoke a Lambda in the current region that in turn invokes a Lambda in the other region.

From https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=914149&#914149:

> The Rules Engine does not support cross-region calls at this time. We encourage customers to keep their IoT applications regionalized as a best practice.
>
> As a workaround to achieve cross region calls we suggest you send to a Lambda in the current region and make the cross region call there.